# How to use AverageIf function in excel macro

Tags: vba, excel

The below code does not work. I am trying to create a pivot with average of Hrs and I don't want the value 0 to be considered in the average.

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AnalyticsPivotTable").PivotFields("Hrs")

    .Orientation = xlDataField

    .Position = 2

        .Function = "=AverageIf(M:M,"">0"")"

        .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
```

Comment: Why the space between average and if? Have you recorded yourself performing this pivot action?

Comment: When using PivotFields and wanting to have a formula, it will not work against absolute ranges as defined in the sample above. 
Suggestion by @Jeeped is valid: Use the macro recorder and see what the output is. Amend from there to suit your specific needs.

Comment: @Jeeped I tried with both AverageIf and Average If. Neither worked.

Comment: @RikSportel my macro creates a pivot of Column M which has time values and then takes the average of it in a table format. How do I record a macro to remove 0 values?

Comment: Make the developer tab visible on the ribbon, hit record, do every step manually, stop recording. The generated code will need clean up, but can be amended to suit your needs.